# Spurious requirement for std::marker::Sized

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, traits

Update: This simpler code ([play](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=use%20std%3A%3Afmt%3A%3ADisplay%3B%0A%0Apub%20fn%20arg(a%3A%20%26str%2C%20b%3A%20%26Display)%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20arg(%22foo%22%2C%20%22bar%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A)) exhibits the same symptoms:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

pub fn arg(a: &str, b: &Display) {
}

fn main() {
    arg("foo", "bar");
}
```

Gives error:

```
<anon>:7:16: 7:21 error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `str` [E0277]
<anon>:7     arg("foo", "bar");
                        ^~~~~
<anon>:7:16: 7:21 note: `str` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
<anon>:7     arg("foo", "bar");
                        ^~~~~
```

But I don't see any reason to require size here. The `a` and `b` are treated the same, they are the same type, and there is no problem with `a`. So

- why does it have problem with `b`, and
- how do I tell it that Trait is not expected to have size known.

In fact, it's a trait type, it never has type known no matter what the underlying type is. So why does it want size?

Oh, and I should not forget: In the actual use-case I need dynamic polymorphism. The function (method) will be chained with arguments of different actual types and the references stored (see the original exhibit below), so I *can't* convert it to `T: Trait + ?Sized`.

---

Original exhibit:

I have some code like the following ([see also on play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=use%20std%3A%3Acollections%3A%3AHashMap%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Amarker%3A%3AMarkerTrait%3B%0A%0Apub%20trait%20Trait%20%3A%20MarkerTrait%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Trait%20for%20str%20%7B%7D%0A%0Apub%20struct%20Struct%3C'a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20args%3A%20HashMap%3C%26'a%20str%2C%20%26'a%20Trait%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3C'a%3E%20Struct%3C'a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20new()%20-%3E%20Self%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Struct%20%7B%20args%3A%20HashMap%3A%3Anew()%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20arg(mut%20self%2C%20key%3A%20%26'a%20str%2C%20value%3A%20%26'a%20Trait)%20-%3E%20Struct%3C'a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.args.insert(key%2C%20value)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20self%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Struct%3A%3Anew().arg(%22foo%22%2C%20%22bar%22)%3B%0A%7D)):

```
pub trait Trait { /* some methods */ }

impl Trait for str { /* some implementation */ }

pub struct Struct<'a> {
    args: HashMap<&'a str, &'a Trait>,
}

impl<'a> Struct<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Struct { args: HashMap::new() }
    }

    pub fn arg(mut self, key: &'a str, value: &'a Trait) -> Struct<'a> {
        self.args.insert(key, value);
        return self;
    }

    // of course there is something to process the collected arguments too
}

fn main() {
    Struct::new().arg("foo", "bar");
}
```

And this gives me error:

```
test.rs:32:30: 32:35 error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `str` [E0277]
test.rs:32     Struct::new().arg("foo", "bar");
                                             ^~~~~
test.rs:32:30: 32:35 note: `str` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
test.rs:32     Struct::new().arg("foo", "bar");
```

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is not spurious.

The raw representation of a trait object is this (`std::raw::TraitObject`):

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct TraitObject {
    pub data: *mut (),
    pub vtable: *mut (),
}
```

The actual data of the object is behind a single pointer.

But how about the dynamically sized types? Taking a slice (`&[T]`) as an example, they are of this form:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Slice<T> {
    pub data: *const T,
    pub len: usize,
}
```

This reference is *two* words: a pointer to the start of the slice *and the number of elements in the slice*.

The size of a `&T` is thus *not actually constant*. If `T` is `Sized`, `&T` and `Box<T>` will be one word, but if `T` is not `Sized`, `&T` and `Box<T>` will be *two* words.

```rust
let word = std::mem::size_of::<usize>();

// References to sized types: one word.
assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<&()>(), 1 * word);
assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<&u8>(), 1 * word);
assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<&String>(), 1 * word);

// References to unsized types: two words.
assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<&[u8]>(), 2 * word);
assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<&str>(), 2 * word);
assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<&std::path::Path>(), 2 * word);
```

What is the impact of this? Well, as mentioned earlier, the definition of trait objects requires that the data pointer be only one word long. To store a dynamically sized type would require *two* words there; I haven’t given much thought to the practicalities of whether it would be *possible* to inflate all trait objects to have two words for data (one of which would be redundant in case of sized objects), so it might or it might not be, but the language has made the decision not to support trait objects of dynamically sized types.

Therefore: if you wish to create a trait object, you will need to do it of a sized type, such as `&str`, rather than a dynamically sized type such as `str`. That means things like `(x: &&str) as &std::fmt::Display;`:

```
arg("foo", &"bar");
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately `&&str` won't help, because the actual string has the necessary lifetime, but the reference to that reference does not. So I'll have to wrap it in something. It would be nice if I could wrap it in something. It would be nice if it could be done without extra allocation, but I fear it won't be.

Comment: ... thinking about it more, the inner reference is a temporary and stays around until end of statement, so in the resulting `&'a&str` the `'a` should be long enough to be returned. Now I just have to find whether I need to fiddle with lifetime in the `impl Trait for &str` to make that work.